# Does .forceignore have a mechanism to ignore most files except for specific files?

Tags: salesforcedx, .forceignore

With `.gitignore`, a `!` represents the negation of the pattern - see [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files).

So I thought this in `.forceignore` might ignore all the pages except the specific one:

```
**/pages/**
!**/pages/Setup.page
```

but it seems to have no effect. (Though commenting out `**/pages/**` doesn't either; not sure what is going on here.)

Is there a way to do this in `.forceignore`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have had issues with this myself in the past I believe .forceignore works slightly differently to .gitignore (I may be wrong here) I believe what you are after is the following.

```
# ignore all pages    
**pages 

# include setup page
!**/Setup.page
```

If you wish to ignore just the setup page

```
# ignore specific file
**/pages/Setup.page
```

Comment: Thanks but that is the approach I'm trying to avoid as I don't want to have to list the large number of pages that are to be ignored, I just want to list the one that should not be ignored.

Comment: Then the top example is what you are after? ignore all pages except for setup?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: check my first example in the answer 

Comment: Have you tested it or have a link to documentation on it - didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I use the above pattern for managing my layouts, it ignores all layouts on force:source:push and force:source:pull except for 1 layout. I agree trying to find documentation is a bit hit and miss. I have found an example of trailhead lwc 
 with a .forceignore on [github](https://github.com/trailheadapps/ebikes-lwc/blob/master/.forceignore) which uses the same pattern for profiles if that helps. Maybe worth checking you are on the latest version of sfdx? In the meantime, I'll give this a whirl soley on pages and report back just incase!

Comment: Good enough for me - thank-you!

Comment: For anybody that runs into the same problem- Make sure that your first line (group to ignore) is based on the file extension, not the path directory. For example, if you want to ignore all Settings files except for Address Settings file, this **DOES** work:

```**.settings-meta.xml
!**/Address.settings-meta.xml```

and this does **NOT** work-

```**/settings
!**/Address.settings-meta.xml```