# How to use forceignore to ignore all fields on an object and add exceptions

Tags: salesforcedx, visualstudiocode, unlocked-package

I am trying to do an ignore on all fields on the object Account and only want to add the custom field Name__c on the object Account. How do I achieve this I tried the following:

```
# Ignore Object
**/main/default/objects/Account/**
!**/main/default/objects/Account/Name__c**
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a previous answer, forceignore works slightly different than normal gitignore; they're using an "older version" of the lib that provides this functionality (see this [Tweet](https://twitter.com/amphro/status/1232830221323243521)).

> Ideally, we want it to be the same as .gitignore but we are using a very old library with no more traction:  https://github.com/codemix/gitignore-parser We are looking at updating to a new library that to be more aligned with .gitignore but no eta.

According to [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/296045/2984), the following should probably work:

```
**/objects/Account
!**/objects/Account/fields/Name__c.field-meta.xml
```

It's my understanding that the wildcards at the end don't work the way you think they do. You simply need to specify the directory to ignore and full file name to include.

The `**` actually means "match any path", while `*` means the more traditional "any part of the file name", so the following may also work:

```
**/objects/Account/**
!**/objects/Account/fields/Name__c*
```

Also see this [.forceignore](https://github.com/trailheadapps/ebikes-lwc/blob/master/.forceignore) file, it may help.